# What do I need to do to be able to create a slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello to whomever is reading this. I am a student studying computer science and for my exit project for the semester I have to code a 3 paged web page. The first page consists of a slide show consisting of 3 images, the images are supposed to cycle every 5 seconds and I'm having trouble trying to figure out the logic behind it. I created a div, and placed 3 images inside and also created an array to hold the 3 images, I would love any helpful hints/tips. This code is incomplete but it's all I can come up with logically so far.

```
function imageCaller(){
  const images = ["opportunity.jpg", "Yu-Yu-Hakusho.png", "Bloodborne.jpg"];
  img.src = images[0];

  for (let images=0; images< images.length; images++)
}
function imageTimer() {
  let timer = setInterval(imageCaller, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making a persistent variable that keeps track of the current index of the array - the current image being displayed. Then, on each iteration (each time the function is called), increment the index, and loop back to 0 when required.

```
const imageCaller = (() => {
  const images = ["opportunity.jpg", "Yu-Yu-Hakusho.png", "Bloodborne.jpg"];
  let index = 0;
  return () => {
    img.src = images[index];
    index = (index + 1) % images.length;
  };
})();

function imageTimer() {
  let timer = setInterval(imageCaller, 5000);
}
```

The `(() => {` and `})();` are there to create the function's own self-contained scope - to encapsulate the `images` and `index` variables. They're only useful to `imageCaller`, so better to avoid polluting the global namespace. If you don't want to do that, an alternative that might be easier to understand is:

```
const images = ["opportunity.jpg", "Yu-Yu-Hakusho.png", "Bloodborne.jpg"];
let index = 0;
function imageCaller(){
  img.src = images[index];
  index = (index + 1) % images.length;
}
function imageTimer() {
  let timer = setInterval(imageCaller, 5000);
}
```

Comment: As a student I appreciate the fact that you gave me the second set of code as a precaution, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an index variable to loop through the image sources.

```
<script>
    const images = ["opportunity.jpg", "Yu-Yu-Hakusho.png", "Bloodborne.jpg"];
    let activeImage = 0;
    function imageCaller(){
            img.src = images[activeImage];
            activeImage=(activeImage + 1) % images.length;
    }
    setInterval(imageCaller, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: `img.src = images[0];` That won't loop through the images.

Comment: @CertainPerformance It was supposed to be img.src = images[activeImage];. My mistake. Corrected.